# Save the value of a wp_dropdown_pages

Tags: php, dropdown, post-meta

I have created a `wp_dropdown_pages` based upon the [WordPress codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages)

```
global $post;
$args = array(
        'date_format'  => get_option('date_format'),
        'depth'        => 0,
        'echo'         => 1,
        'post_type'    => 'page',
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'sort_column'  => 'menu_order, post_title',
        'sort_order'   => 'ASC',
        'value_field'  => 'post_title');
wp_dropdown_pages($args);
```

This displays the dropdown with all of it's pages.

I have two problems.
The main problem is that I don't know how to save this to the database.
I'm used to do it like this:

```
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'url', $_POST['url']);
```

But that doesn't work.

The second problem I have is that I want to have the option selected that is saved in the database. So if a page is saved it should tell me which page is saved.

Hope anyone can enlighten me. Please share how this works and not only a solution so I can understand.... :-)

M.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of your question: in your args variable, you can set the **selected** argument to whatever is saved in your database. See the codex for more details [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_pages/).

I'm currently working on the same issue, I'll update and clarify once I figure everything out out.

**EDIT :** Okay! I DID IT.

Here's my save function:

```
function my_custom_meta_save( $post_id ) {

// Checks save status
$is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
$is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
$is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'my_custom_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'my_custom_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

// Exits script depending on save status
if ($is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
    return;
}


// Checks for input and sanitizes/saves if needed
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'meta_key' ] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_key', $_POST[ 'meta_key' ] );
}

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_custom_meta_save' )
```

Annnnd here's my callback function:

```
function my_custom_meta_callback() {
// Get the stored value from the database
global $post;
$meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'sos_internal_gallery', true);

// TO DO: Exclude galleries that are already being displayed elsewhere
$args = array(
    'echo'                  => true,
    'name'                  => 'sos_internal_gallery',
    'id'                    => 'sos_internal_gallery',
    'show_option_none'      => 'Select a slider',
    'post_type'             => 'sosslider',
    'sort_column'           => 'post_title',
    'selected'              => $meta
);

// Create drop down that lists all published sliders
wp_dropdown_pages( $args );
}
```

Hope this helps! It only took me all day to figure out.